# AS3 - Finding the highest y-coordinate for a given x-coordinate in BitmapData?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, game-physics, bitmapdata

I'm making a platformer. Here is what I have so far: http://megaswf.com/s/2486396 (move around and jump with arrowkeys).

I'm using the ground's bitmap data to test collisions with the player's coordinates, and the player is sinking into the ground a few pixels (especially when walking uphill). To prevent this, I want the player's y coordinate to instantly change so that the player is sitting on top of the ground. Here is what I'm working on:

```
    if (groundClipBmpData.hitTest(rLoc, 255, bLocFuture)) {
        playerClip.y = ???
    }
```

I want the player's y-coordinate to change to become the highest pixel of the groundClipBmpData at the player's x coordinate.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the other question:

Use `while` instead of `if`

Like this:

```
while(groundClipBmpData.hitTest(rLoc, 255, playerClipBmpData, bLocFuture, 255))
{
        playerClip.y--;
}
playerClip.y++;
```

The fastest way would be to calculate and store the highest coordinate values in advance inside an array and then use the 'x' position of the player to determine the 'y' of the ground.

Comment: Thanks :) It works. I'm not sure it's the fastest solution, though.

Comment: probably not, would you like a faster one? I would not worry about it unless you discover it is a 'bottleneck' in your game. You can check how much time it takes to computer by using getTimer() before and after the loop and subtracting: after - before : this will give you the amount of milliseconds it takes, I suspect it will be 0.